# form is not submitting when click on button, when data retrieved using jquery post method

Tags: php, jquery

I am retrieving data using ajax post method, its retrieved.Entire table is displayed in division, within table button with form, when button clicks form is not submitting to target file, its redirects to same page. Please can any one help me? Its usefull for me. Code is as follows :

```
 **jquery**
  $("#search").keyup(function(e) {
  var val=$(this).val();
   if(val=='')
   {
       //alert("empty");
       $("#resp").hide("");

   }
   else
   {
     $.post("search_db.php",{search:val},function(response){
     $("#resp").show("");
     $("#resp").html(response);
     });
   }
 });     

  **search_db.php**
  <tr align="center">
    <td><?php echo $i;  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['acc_num'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['cust_name'];  ?></td>
    <td><a href="tel:<?php echo $rows['phone_code'].$rows['contact']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['phone_code'].$rows['contact'];  ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_bal['bal'];  ?></td>
     <td><form action="account_statement.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="hide_id" value="<?php echo $rows['acc_num']; ?>" /><input type="hidden" name="hide_search" value="<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>" /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">View</button></form></td>
 </tr>

 **Html**
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<div id="number"  style="padding-right:15px;">
   <div class="form-group" >
      <label class="control-label">Search</label><label id="error_search"></label>
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Name or Phone or Place" required class="form-control" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you having two forms in a page?

Comment: explain coding functionality

Comment: You need to explain whats on its own page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with full path..?

eg: http://www.example.com/account_statement.php

Or

simple put / before account_statement.php

so your form action attribute is something like action="/account_statement.php"

Answer (score 0):

consider this one table

```
<table id="table">
     <tr>
          <td>...1</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

just replace div id

```
$("#resp").html(response);
or
//document.window.reload(); //if u want reload
```

or

You can use plugin also(js plugin)

Datatable (ref this page)

```
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type="submit" />` instead `<button type="submit">`. Some browsers could not act normally if you use `<button>` in html form.